# How to make the editor field active for the entire row/ or few columns on edit of a field extjs grid panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs5, sencha-architect

I have a grid panel with cell editing plugin with four columns on edit on second column I want to make the remaining columns/ few of the remaining columns editor active so that the user will understand they are mandatory just like how we do in forms. I am already setting a color for the mandatory fields but only on click on that particular column I am able to see. This might be the behaviour of the cell editing plugin. Any suggestion on how to achieve this [Fiddle sample](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2364)

Comment: If you want multiple editors for the same row to be active at the same time, you probably should use a RowEditor instead.

Comment: Expanding on Guilherme Lopes comment:
Use a Roweditor and conditionally disable/enable columns/fields for edit depending on where the user clicked.

Not sure what you mean by setting colors for the mandatory fields, though? The Fiddle shows no effort in that direction.